# AJAX code confusion using GET method

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, windows, web

I bought a book and began learning how to use AJAX and someone gave me a practice assignment where I have to enter values into one div and perform an AJAX get request to a website she gave me to receive the information in the right div. Maybe I am doing the AJAX get request incorrectly following this book. If anyone could point me in the right direction I would appreciate it. This is not for school, and I have no experience in web scripting languages but willing to learn. Just give my javascript a look and maybe you can help me out. I am not sure yet on how to display the information after it has been received but I know for sure I do not want to load another page when hitting the submit button!

Also, I have a weird way of lining up my code from programming in C++ for about 4 years now. I have developed it over time and sorry if it is hard to understand. If so, then I can format it a proper way and re-post. Also, I am trying to learn how to use the AJAX GET method, not the POST method. And I want to return the information in JSON.

```
<html>

    <head>

            <style type="text/css">
                    #header {
                            text-align: left;
                    }
                    #wrapper {

                            margin:bottom;
                            width:100%;

                    }

                    #sub-left {
                            float:left;
                width:225px;
            height:215px;
            border:1px solid black; 
            position: relative;
            text-align: left;
                    }
                    #sub-right {
            padding-left: 52px;
                            float:left;
            width:60%;
            height:45%;
            border:1px solid black; 
            position: relative;
            text-align: left;

                    }
        #sub-leftmost {

                            float:left;
            width:10%;
            height:100%;
            position: relative;
            text-align: left;
                    }

            </style>


    <script type=”text/javascript”>
    // function create GetXmlHttpObject
    function GetXmlHttpObject(){
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    return new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    if (window.ActiveXObject){
    // code for IE6, IE5
    return new ActiveXObject(“Microsoft.XMLHTTP”);
    }
    return null;
    }

    function submitFormWithAjax(){
    var myAjaxGetrequest = new GetXmlHttpObject();

    var t2lName=document.testForm.namebox.value;
    var t2lEmail=document.testForm.ebox.value;
    var t2lAddress=document.testForm.addbox.value;
    var t2lPhone=document.testForm.phnbox.value;

    var parameters = "name=" + encodeURIComponent(t2lName) 
           + "&email=" +encodeURIComponent(t2lEmail)
           + "&address=" + encodeURIComponent(t2lAddress)
           + "&phone=" +encodeURIComponent(t2lPhone);

    myAjaxGetrequest.open("GET", "websitetosendandgetfrom.com" + parameters, true);
    myAjaxGetrequest.send( );

    if (myAjaxGetrequest.readyState==4){
    if(myAjaxGetrequest.status==200 || window.location.href.indexOf("http")==-1){
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=myAjaxGetrequest.responseText
    document.getElementById(“testForm”).style.display = “none”;
    }
    else    {
    document.getElementById(“testForm”).innerHTML=”An error has occured making the request”;
    }
    }
    }
    }   



</script>
    </head>

    <body>

<div id="wrapper">

    <div id="sub-leftmost">


    </div>
</div>


    <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header"><h1>Quiz</h1></div>
    <div id="sub-left">
<form name = 'testForm'>
<FONT COLOR="CC3300",font size="5">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>User Info</b></FONT>
<br />

&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Full Name: <br /><center><input type="text"  size="25" id =         "namebox" /></center>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Email Address: <br /><center><input type="text"  size="25" id = "ebox" /></center>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Address: <br /><center><input type="text"  size="25" id = "addbox" /></center>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Phone Number: <br /><center><input type="text"  size="25" id = "phnbox" />
<a href=”#” onclick=”submitFormWithAjax();”>Finished!</a>
</form>

    </div>
    </div>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="sub-right">

    </div>
</div>


    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: At least one problem is with the second function, submitFormWithAjax. Here's a link with revised formatting and a bit of error checking via an alert that lets you know when the JavaScript is loading. http://pastebin.com/X7ueZpnQ

Answer (score 1):

The request is asynchronous and will only call a callback function when its status changes.

Basically, all the code that depends upon the request's status change needs to be wrapped into the callback of the AJAX request:

```
myAjaxGetrequest.send();

myAjaxGetrequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (myAjaxGetrequest.readyState==4){
    ...
```

Comment: I added that line to the code, I am still getting the same thing. It is opening a new page for some reason that does not exist. I just want the request to appear in the div to the right.

Comment: Does anyone know how I receive the information back from the server?

Comment: Alright, so I am almost there. I had an error in my code up there that was blocking some other things from happening. Now if I can figure out how to send my data in JSON format to the .com server then I can figure out how to retrieve it. Here is my current code on pastebin, if anyone can help please comment. http://pastebin.com/ctNDg9gv